# Form token does not match when user refreshes page

Tags: php, session, session-hijacking

I wrote the following three functions in an attempt to prevent session Hijacking. They work. I call set_auth_token at the beginning of the script. Then in the html form I call get_auth_token. After the form has been posted I call check_auth_token. However, sometimes after a user has filled in a form, and they fill it in incorrectly, they tend to press F5/Refresh. This causes the page to 'die'. It does not happen before a form has been filled in.

What can I do to improve these, so that they do not die each time a user presses refresh?

```
function set_auth_token()
{
   if (!isset($_SESSION['auth_token']))
   {
      $_SESSION['auth_token'] = hash('sha256',rand().time().$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   }
}
```

get_auth_token is always called after set_auth_token has been called, hence it dies if it cannot find an auth token:

```
function get_auth_token()
{
   if (isset($_SESSION['auth_token']))
   {
      return $_SESSION['auth_token'];   
   }
   else
   {
      die('"No auth token."');
   }
}
```

The function that causes the page to die:

```
function check_auth_token()
{
   if (array_key_exists('auth_token', $_SESSION) && array_key_exists('auth_token', $_POST))
   {
      if ($_SESSION['auth_token'] == $_POST['auth_token'])
      {
         $_SESSION['auth_token'] = hash('sha256', rand() . time() . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
      }
      else
      {
         die('Woah! It seems like you pressed Refresh (or Back/Forward). Just click here to sort it out.'); # TODO: hyperlink silly
      }
   }
   else
   {
      die('no auth token');
   }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess (based on your comment) is that when the user refreshes, they are sending their POST data again, but the `auth_token` is being updated at the beginning of the script, and hence the value in the `$_POST` (generated on previous page) will no longer equal the new value (generated at the beginning of the script).

You should look at [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to stop the resending of Post data.

You may also consider not regenerating the key until you have validated or invalidated the existing one.

Comment: It normally says: 'Woah! It seems like you pressed Refresh (or Back/Forward). Just click here to sort it out.' It's never says 'no auth token'. So I think it's the second condition.

Comment: @john Thanks for the clarification. I assume a `var_dump($_SESSION, $_POST)` clearly shows the `auth_token` member is different?

Comment: thanks I looked at it, so basically I need to send a 303 header after validating data?